# Avoiding Cross-Contamination of Auto Suggest Dictionaries

Tags: languages, auto-correct

I recently switched to the Galaxy S5 and am encountering what I can only think to describe as cross-contamination of my auto suggest dictionary. I use multiple languages every day, and so the first thing I did when I set up my new phone was to  install the German, Turkish, and Spanish keyboards (stock keyboards, not third-party apps).

As a result, now when I type in English on the English keyboard, I get auto suggestions based on the other languages installed.

For example:

> for -> för
>   I (capital i) ->  İ
>   Ask -> aşk

It is almost as if there is a single dictionary that now contains entries for all languages, regardless of which keyboard is selected.

So, is there any way to prevent this "cross-contamination"?

Answer (score 1):

While not as complete of an answer as I'd like, I was able to improve my typing experience vastly by doing the following:

First, it is important to understand the difference between auto-correct (or auto-replace, as it is known in the settings) and predictive text. Predictive text, when enabled,  is what is shown in the black bar above the keyboard. Auto-replace automatically replaces whatever string you've typed with the most probable string pulled from a dictionary file.

**Instructions:**
By going into my keyboard settings and enabling predictive text **AND** auto-replace for **ALL** installed input languages I was able to greatly improve the function of the keyboard. For whatever reason, it would seem that unless auto-replace is enabled for all languages, the probability algorithm doesn't effectively limit it's results to the current input language.

I tested English, German, Turkish and Spanish and was able to receive useful predictions and auto-replacements for each language.

That said, it isn't a perfect solution. Text predictions at the beginning of a sentence are more likely to contain unhelpful suggestions (probably due to limited data fed into the prediction algorithm), and intruders do still occasionally make their way to the front of the auto-correct list.

For this reason, it's probably important to absolutely avoid lazily entering text in a language other than the currently selected keyboard in order not to muddle up the predictions.

**Notes:**
It is still unclear to me how the dictionaries are actually stored on the device, so hopefully a more in-the-know user can provide a more satisfactory answer in the future. From the observations I've made, it would seem that a single, combined - language dictionary file is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess yes there is a way to prevent this cross contamination, head over the Settings>Application manager>Choose Samsung Keyboard>Clear the Data stored by the application and it will reset back all the suggestion to back in the time you first used your device. See if that can be of any use.

Comment: While I appreciate your suggestion, i don't wish to do away with suggestions, but instead to confine them to the currently selected input language. For example, I shouldn't be getting 'ferric'  as a suggestion when typing "ferrocarril" while Spanish is the selected input language.

Comment: Well @Milchgesicht In that case I should say I just ran out of options, because all the time the Samsung Keyboard is collection the information you have stored and based on that suggestion is feed. I can't comment more over it rather than try using some other keyboard application like swift keyboard etc. See it that can help in avoiding cross contamination.